# Formula to cut word from a text string

Tags: formula

Hi I have a field as 'Category' which can take string separated by comma (,) e.g as below

```
Category = Exhibition_Sport and Leisure, Family, Family_Sport and Leisure, Sport
```

I am trying to cut the last word from Right i.e `'Sport'` into custom field 'Vertical' and the rest of the text into another custom field 'Event Type'.

Also the above string can have either one or more than one word separated by comma. If the string has only one word say 'Sport' it should be updated to 'Vertical'

```
I/p  Category = Exhibition_Sport and Leisure, Family, Family_Sport and Leisure, Sport


o/p Vertical = Sport

Event Type = Exhibition_Sport and Leisure, Family, Family_Sport and Leisure
```

What is the best way to implement the formulae?

Comment: take a look at the string instance methods http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_String_instance_methods.htm  `substringBeforeLast(String)` , `substringAfterLast(String)` , etc

Comment: Please try to use tags specifically related to your question, this is useful for attracting people with the right knowledge to your question.

Comment: Entry to 'Category' field comes via REST API from a third party system. Based on the entry, two custom formula fields are to be updated 'Vertical' and 'Event Type' as per rule specified earlier.

Comment: @Max: You should flesh that out and write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Sdry thanks for that - "wrong quadrant" completely (blush). I clearly missed the "formula" reference at the end of the question (blush)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a good understand of [formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US) for this to work. Specifically, [`IF()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#IF), [`BEGINS()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#BEGINS), [`RIGHT()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#RIGHT), [`LEFT()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#LEFT), [`TRIM()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#TRIM), [`FIND()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#FIND), and [`CONTAINS()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CONTAINS).

The following should be able to set your `Vertical__c`. It will check the `Category__c` starting from the right and proceed to increment the string's length by 1 until that string begins with a ",". Once it does, it also verifies that the string does not contain any other apostraphes. If it does not, that is the last unique String in the list.

```
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 1), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 0), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 0))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 2), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 1), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 1))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 3), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 2), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 2))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 4), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 3), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 3))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 5), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 4), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 4))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 6), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 5), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 5))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 7), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 6), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 6))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 8), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 7), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 7))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 9), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 8), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 8))
)
IF(
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 10), ","
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Category__c, 9), ","
    ),
    TRIM(RIGHT(Category__c, 9))
)
```

You can expand this count for a bit to check more characters to the right of the end until you hit the maximum character limit of 5000. This formula is currently around 1800 characters. You should probably be able to get up to 20 characters checked easily.

You should then be able to utilize a function similar to what Michael detailed out to get the `Event_Type__c`. It is important to note that you must not utilize the full 5000 characters in `Vertical__c` to ensure it can still be used in this formula.

```
LEFT(
    Category__c, 
    FIND(", " + Vertical__c, Category__c)
)
```

This will take all characters to the left of the `Vertical__c` in `Category__c`. Note that the ", " is prepended to the beginning of the `Vertical__c` to ensure they are removed from the `Event_Type__c`.

---

**Note:** I have not been able to test this myself, but this should give you a good starting point. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve a fully dynamical solution, as the field formulas do not feature any function which might find last occurrence of a string/character. If there existed such a function, you might easily accomplish what you are looking for with a formula which would resemble something like this:

```
IF(
    CONTAINS(Category__c, ","),
    RIGHT(Category__c, LEN(Category__c)-FINDLAST(",")),
    Category__c
)
```

However, as no such function exists (FINDLAST()), but rather only [FIND()](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#FIND) function, you might resort to a 'dirty fix' solution, which would handle each case specifically, for every number of commas occurring in your **Category__c** field. I.e. for each increasing number of comma occurences, you should move the starting index (third param) of the main [FIND()](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#FIND) function a bit further to the right:

```
CASE(
    LEN(Category__c) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Category__c, ',', '')),   // number of commas in Category__c field
    1, RIGHT(Category__c, LEN(Category__c) - FIND(",", Category__c)),
    2, RIGHT(Category__c, LEN(Category__c) - FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c))),
    3, RIGHT(Category__c, LEN(Category__c) - FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c))) ),
    4, RIGHT(Category__c, LEN(Category__c) - FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c)))) ),
    5, RIGHT(Category__c, LEN(Category__c) - FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c, FIND(",", Category__c))))) ),
    Category__c     // default
)
```

Please have in mind that this is a dirty fix and the fiven example might not work propperly should you have more than 5 commas occurring in the Category__c field. Still, you might add additional cases for each additional comma should you be able to approximate this number at all.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to remove last word of string, based on Jesse Altman's string.  Sub "Street" for "Category__c"

```
IF(
    (BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 1), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 0), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) -  0)
,
 IF(
    (BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 2), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 1), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 1)
,
 IF(
    (BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 3), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 2), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 2)
,
 IF(
    (BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 4), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 3), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 3)
,
 IF(
    (BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 5), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 4), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 4)
,
 IF(
    (BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 6), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 5), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 5)
,
 IF((
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 7), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 6), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 6)
,
 IF((
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 8), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 7), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 7)
,
 IF((
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 9), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 8), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 8)
, 
IF((
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 10), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 9), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 9)
, 
IF((
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 11), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 10), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 10)
, 
IF((
    BEGINS(
        RIGHT( Street , 12), " "
    )
    &&
    !CONTAINS(
        RIGHT(Street, 11), " "
    )),
     LEFT( Street ,LEN( Street ) - 11)
, Street))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For o/p Vertical = Sport
Use Formula:REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE({!Reseller_name}), FIND(",",REVERSE({!Reseller_name})) - 1)).

To get below result:

Event Type = Exhibition_Sport and Leisure, Family, Family_Sport and Leisure

Use Formula:
REVERSE( TRIM(RIGHT(REVERSE({!Reseller_name}) , LEN(REVERSE({!Reseller_name}) ) - FIND(",",REVERSE({!Reseller_name}) ))))